# mesh rotation error after i attached the bones

Tags: mesh, bones, properties

**firstly , i create a toy with several boxes, then i create several bones**
[image]

**seconldly , i set the mesh's parent to any bone**

[image]

**and last, i found the body mesh's orientation changed by the bone, what's the problem with my model?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, please share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: thanks for help , i add more bones , but the mesh and texture is not right all the time

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question, could you please reformulate? everything looks fine when you parent the mesh to the armature, except you need to correct the IK Pole Angle and bend a bit elbows and knees in Edit mode to make arms and leges bend in the good direction...

Comment: thanks, i updated my picture , the mesh was distorted by the bone , it look like  something wrong with the model 
i have't fond the error !

Comment: I think you need to set the IK Pole Angle value, please check my answer

Comment: thanks very much , i fixed it by adjust my pole angle, nice help     ~ ^ ~

Answer (score 0):

Once you've parented your mesh, you often need to corect the *IK Pole Angle* so that the mesh doesn't get twisted by the *IK*:

[image]

Also, always bend a bit the knees and elbows in *Edit* mode so that Blender knows how to bend these limbs once rigged:

[image]